# How to use client certificate for HTTPs requests in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm writing an app that needs to make some HTTPs requests that use a client certificate. However, I can't find any documents on how to install the certificate and then load it for use. I know that you can use the certificate by making a `HttpBaseProtocolFilter` and adding a certificate but how do you load the certificate for use here? And if you have a .pfx file with your client certificate, how do you install it with your package?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserCertificateStore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I ended up figuring this out using a mix of the Portable.BouncyCastle NuGet package and some UWP APIs. Some sample (pseudo-ish) code for what I did is below:

```
// Asymmetric key pair
RsaKeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
keyPairGenerator.Init(
    new KeyGenerationParameters(
        new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()), 2048));
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

// Create certificate
X509V3CertificateGenerator generator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
generator.SetSubjectDN("foo");
generator.SetIssuerDN("foo");
generator.SetSerialNumber(new BigInteger("12345").Abs());
generator.SetNotBefore(DateTime.UtcNow);
generator.SetNotAfter(DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromYears(1));
generator.SetPublicKey(keyPair.Public);

BouncyCastleX509Certificate certificate =
    generator.Generate(
        new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA1WithRSA", keyPair.Private));

// Create PKCS12 certificate bytes.
Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12Store();
X509CertificateEntry certificateEntry = new X509CertificateEntry(certificate);
string friendlyName = "Friendly Name";
string password = "password";
store.SetCertificateEntry(friendlyName, certificateEntry);
store.SetKeyEntry(
    friendlyName,
    new AsymmetricKeyEntry(keyPair.Private),
    new X509CertificateEntry[] { certificateEntry });
string pfxData;
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(512))
{
    store.Save(memoryStream, password.ToCharArray(), this.SecureRandom);
    pfxData = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray().AsBuffer());
}

// Add the certificate to the cert store
await CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(
    pfxData,
    password,
    ExportOption.NotExportable,
    KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent,
    InstallOptions.DeleteExpired,
    friendlyName);

// Read the UWP cert from the cert store
Certificate uwpCertificate =
    (await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(
        new CertificateQuery { FriendlyName = friendlyName }))[0];

// Create the UWP HTTP client.
HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);
filter.ClientCertificate = uwpCertificate;
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(filter);

// Profit!
```